# Plot3d of explanation of partial partial derivatives

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a two functions together that looks like this:

[image]

But I am only able to come up with this;"which is clearly wrong"

```
Plot3D[{x^2 + x + y^2, x + y}, {x, -20000, 20000}, {y, -20000, 20000}]
```

I have looked through the help section but somehow I am not getting how to change it.

Ps: I do not care about the range that its plotted in.

Comment: The vertical plane in your figure is not a depiction of a *function*, as it is multi-valued. Therefore it can't be plotted by Plot3D, which is meant for functions only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a variant plotting all within `ContourPlot` and using `MeshFunctions` to highlight variable kept constant.

```
ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + x + y^2 - z == 0, x == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
  2}, {z, 0, 6}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Green, Thick}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way, I am sure there is a better way, but for now....

```
Remove["Global`*"];
eq1 = x^2 + x + y^2;
eqX = x == 0;(*for the yz plan surface*)
lim = 20;
zlim = 800;(*adjust as needed when changing p1*)
p1 = Plot3D[eq1, {x, -lim, lim}, {y, -lim, lim}];
p2 = ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@eqX, {x, -lim, lim}, {y, -lim, lim}, {z, 0, zlim}, 
   ImageSize -> 250];
Show[{p1, p2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To add more surfaces, just add its equation, for example:

```
eqY = y == 0; (*for the xz plan  surface *)
p2 = ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{eqX, eqY}], {x, -lim, lim}, {y, -lim, lim}, {z, 0, zlim},
  ImageSize -> 250];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

see [ContourPlot3D.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/)  and [Plot3D.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/)